# How to generate multiple copies of same PDF XFA form using iText7?

Tags: itext7, xfa

We were using Acroforms before and able to generate multiple copies of the same form using PdfMerger. After we switched to XFA to handle dynamic forms, we are not able to generate multiple copies anymore. We are still using the same function which uses PdfMerger (similar to the code snippet below):

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

//Add pages from the first document
PdfDocument firstSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
merger.merge(firstSourcePdf, 1, firstSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());

//Add pages from the second pdf document
PdfDocument secondSourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
merger.merge(secondSourcePdf, 1, secondSourcePdf.getNumberOfPages());

firstSourcePdf.close();
secondSourcePdf.close();
pdf.close();
```

Comment: XFA is a completely different form architecture which only partially is supported by iText. To merge XFA forms, first extract the XFA XML definitions with iText. Then build a new XFA XML from it holding multiple copies of the original. This step is outside the scope of iText (to my knowledge at least, but ask their sales). This new XFA XML you can insert back into the PDF using iText.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code snippets for both retrieving xml definitions from XFA and also creating a new XFA XML document using the merged xml?

Comment: *"Can you share the relevant code snippets for [...] creating a new XFA XML document using the merged xml?"* - unfortunately, I have no experience with creating xfa XML files and only mediocre experience with understanding them. But most of xfa is publicly specified, so you should be able to grab the specs and determine a way to merge them. I can provide code for retrieving xfa XML from PDFs and storing xfa xml in there again.

Comment: ok, I'll look into this myself. Btw, do you know if PdfMerger would work for merging multiple copies of the same form for a flattened XFA? As we also have a requirement to provide flattened PDFs.